# Proving if there exist a subsequence converging to $1/n$, there exist a subsequence converging to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let {$x_k$} be a sequence and suppose for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist a subsequence converging to $1/n$. Prove there exist a subsequence converging to $0$.

Is this as simple as saying since $1/n$ converges to $0$, we can look at the case when $n$ is infinitely large and therefore the existing subsequence that converges to $1/n$ will in turn converge to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

As there is a subsequence converging to $\frac 12,$ there is an element within $\frac 1{2^2}$ of it. There is a later element within $\frac 1{3^2}$ of $\frac 13$....